# Given a string of HTML, what is the best way to look for floating < >

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Given an HTML string:

```
myhtml = "<title> my title </title>"
```

How can I write a function that returns `true` if there is a floating/unescaped `<` or `>`, along with the offending character itself? Examples:

```
myhtml = "<title> my title </title>"
hasFloating(myhtml) => false

myhtml = "<title> < </title>"
hasFloating(myhtml) => true, <

myhtml = "<title> > </title>"
hasFloating(myhtml) => true, >
```

Keep in mind this string could be one huge piece of HTML code with multiple elements in it. I'm also okay with one function checking whether an unescaped char exists and a second returning the offender character itself

Edit: For the record, I am also using the `mechanize` gem in this project

Comment: You'll need an HTML parser if you want to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if there's an angle bracket that is not closed, you don't need a fancy gem.
You can just use `StringScanner`.

```rb
require 'strscan'

def has_floating(html)
  open_angle = 0
  scanner = StringScanner.new(html)
  while scanner.scan(/<|>/)
    case scanner.matched
    when '<'
      return [true, '<'] if open_angle == 1
      open_angle += 1
    when '>'
      return [true, '>'] if open_angle == 0
      open_angle -= 1
    end
    scanner.scan_until(/[^<>]+/)
  end
  return false
end

myhtml = "<title> my title </title>"
puts has_floating(myhtml).inspect
#=> false

myhtml = "<title> < </title>"
puts has_floating(myhtml).inspect
#=> [true, "<"]

myhtml = "<title> > </title>"
puts has_floating(myhtml).inspect
#=> [true, ">"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to get into the HTML part, since writing a HTML parser is a project by itself.

You can return multiple values by simply returning an array.

```
def hasFloating(html)
  # extract a < or > character surrounded by two spaces
  char = html[/(?<= )[<>](?= )/]
  [!!char, char] # !!char converts char into a boolean
end
```

Then use [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to extract the values:

```
bool, char = hasFloating("<title> my title </title>") # bool = false, char = nil
bool, char = hasFloating("<title> < </title>")        # bool = true,  char = "<"
bool, char = hasFloating("<title> > </title>")        # bool = true,  char = ">"
```

Comment: The question is how to check if there is an angle bracket that doesn't have a matching pair. Your code checks whether there is an angle bracket that is preceeded and followed by `space` characthers.

Comment: @Adrian That is not all the question is about. *"How can I write a function that returns true ..., along with the offending character itself?"*

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer using the `nokogiri` gem:

```
htmlStr = Nokogiri::HTML(html).text
# check for < or > in htmlSTR
```

It basically parses the HTML down and removes all the tags:

```
html = <title> < </title>
# parse with nokogiri
=> " < "
```

Which can then be used to check for floating < >.

Comment: It might work, but you're using a katana to cut a paper. It's unnecesarily heavy and sometimes the result is not what you want. Nokogiri parses the whole html string first. My solution only finds the first angle bracket that's not closed/opened and exits. It should be a lot faster than nokogiri when the html string is huge.